# Installing Flask on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask

I'm having difficulty installing Flask on my Ubuntu machine. In fact, I tried 2 different Ubuntu computers and neither of them worked.

I followed this tutorial https://pythonprogramming.net/creating-first-flask-web-app/  where all steps are well explained.

The problem is. When I type `localhost:5000` or just `localhost` or `127.0.0.1:5000` I get "Can't connect. Something is broken" you know that sort of message you get when server can't find index.html or index.php

Everything during the installation went okay. The only thing that didn't work well was installing virtual environment. It downloaded okay but when I ran `sudo virtualenv xyz` I got `No such command`. But Django & Flask can work without it so it shouldn't be an issue.

Any ideas ?

I deleted those as Flask don't need files to be named index.html.

Comment: Did you ensure that the server runs as well as you expected? Do the minimal example from this site to ensure that everything with your installation works well. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#a-minimal-application

Comment: I'll try that later. I'm experiencing power cut and all street is affected. I'm typing this on my phone. Thanks for the tip btw. I'll keep you updated. Cheers.

Comment: I tried that "minimal example". Didn't work either. I'm leaving Flask. I don't have time to deal with this. I'd stick with Django but I really dislike its inflexibility when it comes to user authentication. I guess I'll build my project in PHP framework. Much less headache.